# ADO.NET Empty database Output (mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, database, ado.net

I'm making alittle program that gets some data out of a database with ADO.NET. The thing is, after I open the connection it doesn't show ANYTHING in the console. If I output something before the connection.. everything is fine, but after it's just clean black.

What I'm doing is reading a table and output the query output. Nothing big but can't seem to find my missing item..

Many thanks

**Answer: I left the console open for a while and I had a connection time-out. C# was still busy handling the conn.Open() until the time out kicked in.**

```
public void ReadVoorraad() {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=postorder2;User ID=root;Password=****");
        SqlDataReader rdr = null;

        try {

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from voorraad", conn);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read()) {
                Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("------ End of stream -------");
        } finally {
            if (rdr != null) { rdr.Close(); }
            if (conn != null) { conn.Close(); }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: are you using mySql or MS SQL server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that there was some exception. Try adding this to your code to get more diagnostic information out of your `ReadVoorraad` method:

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
SqlDataReader rdr = null;

try {
    conn = new SqlConnection(...);

    ...
} catch (Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Error: " + e.Message);
    throw;
} finally {
    if (rdr != null) { rdr.Close(); }
    if (conn != null) { conn.Close(); }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't provide enough information. As I tried the catch method like you provide in this answer. I didn't get any output. Even with a user defined writeline.. Just a clean empty console window. As it doesn't show anything anymore when I do conn.Open();

Comment: @JesseStruyvelt I doubt this would be the source of your error, but perhaps you should create the `SqlConnection` within the `try` block - see my update.

Comment: Tried to create the new connection in the try block. No avail. Same problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Think I found it. Let the console open for a while and then it gave an error after about 2 minutes. Couldn't reach the sql server. As it's available trough my commandline.. Weird

Comment: ahh, it's a connection timeout issue. you can set the timeout to something less than 2 minutes with the [`ConnectionTimeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout.aspx) property